# How do I repeat the table header in doubles?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want the table header to repeat with ng-repeat in doubles like so:

a b | a b |

Not aa | bb.

The way I'm doing right now it's just printing a b |

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <span ng-repeat="averageDefinitionFormula in averageDefinitionFormulas">
                        <th>
                            <label translate>Average</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label translate>Examining Board Average</label>
                        </th>
                    </span>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody> etc...
```

...

Comment: what data you have in averageDefinitionFormulas share the sample

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by just putting two divs inside the td and using bootstrap columns to adjust the layout.

```
  <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" ng-repeat="averageDefinitionFormula in averageDefinitionFormulas">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"> <label translate>Average</label> </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"> <label translate>Examining Board Average </label> </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```